# How to keep image in position with toggle

Tags: javascript, css, toggle

I have an image and when the arrow button is clicled it slides to the left, but does not stay in that position. When the arrow button is clicked again it should close. Any idea on how to keep position of an element?

JS

```
const IT = document.querySelector(".tech img")
const ITSolutions = document.getElementById("IT");

IT.addEventListener("click",()=>{ 
  if(IT){
    ITSolutions.classList.toggle("slideLeft");
    modalLeft.classList.add("showDescrip");
  }
})
```

CSS

```
.slideLeft{
    animation: slideLeft 2s 1 ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes slideLeft {
    0%{ transform: translate(0%, 0);}
    100%{ transform: translate(-50%, 0);}
}
```

Comment: Add an extra rule to `.slideLeft` – `transform: translate(-50%, 0);`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @motto in the comment section;

```
.slideLeft{
    animation: slideLeft 0.5s 1 ease-in;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

Solves the issue I was having.